# Prototype - spiceworks bulk close tickets select

Tags: javascript, select, prototype

I am looking for guidance to look for a way to accomplish some difficulty in programming that I don't have the experience to create.

I am using [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com) with a custom plugin called [Plugin Bulk Delete and Close](http://community.spiceworks.com/plugin/340)  and it works fine but I need an additional logic. I have a custom attribute called Master Number where I can specify relations on tickets [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn3wa.png).

I'm looking for a way that in case a ticket is selected to close all with the same Master Number. Well, my programming is very limited and I just started with prototype and reading about jquery for a month and a half now. Any help or direction is all I need this is possibly very simple but not for me.

```
 SPICEWORKS.app.helpdesk.ready(function(){

if(document.URL.indexOf("Master_View") >= 0){


  if ($('Multi-Toolbar') === null)
  {
 var toolbarDInsert = '<a class="delete toolbar_buton" href="#" id="plugin-Dactions">';
  var toolbarCInsert = '<a class="clopen toolbar_buton" href="#" id="plugin-Cactions"><span class="inner icon">Close/Open Ticket(s)</span></a>';
  var cbInsert = '<span style="float:left;"><input type="checkbox" class="plugin-operation" name="cbselection" /></span>';
  var HdInsert = 'div#ticket-list-body table tr td.cell-status';
  var thinsert = '<div id="Multi-Toolbar" class="sui-toolbar"><tr><th><input type="checkbox" id="plugin-all" /></th></tr></div>';
  plugin.includeStyles();  

  $('primary').insert({top:thinsert});
  $('Multi-Toolbar').insert(toolbarCInsert);
  $('Multi-Toolbar').insert(toolbarDInsert);  

    var insertcheckbox = function(actions){
    actions.style.width = '2.5em';
    actions.insert({top:cbInsert});
    };

    $$(HdInsert).each(insertcheckbox);


  $('plugin-Cactions').observe('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
    var entries = $$('input.plugin-operation').select(function(input){


      return input.checked;
    }).collect(function(input){
      return input.up('tr').id.replace('ticket-', '');
    });
    if(entries.size() > 0){    
    var answer = confirm('You are about to Close / Open ' + entries.size() + ' Ticket(s) Relying on the Ticket(s) state. \nContinue ?') ;   
    if (answer){
      entries.each(function(entry){ new Ajax.Request('/tickets/toggle_status/' + entry);

      });
    }}  
    if(entries.size() <= 0){
    alert('No ticket(s) selected, please select at least one ticket');    
    }
  });

  $('plugin-all').observe('click',function (e) {
  var toggle = $('plugin-all').checked;
  $$('div#ticket-list-body input[type=checkbox]').each(function(check) {
  check.checked = toggle;
  });
});  
}
}
});
```